# Android and PyQt application

Tags: android, python, qt, pyqt, port

I wrote an application using PyQt for Windwos/Linux and I want to port it to Android. Application is simple, has 2 levels of GUI and I do not want to implement touch functions, but to control application using USB keyboard.
I am using this project:
[android-python27](http://code.google.com/p/android-python27/)
to interpret my PyQt code for Android, but it doesn't work. I suppose that I have to modify code, but I do not know how. I only found one sample for using android-python27:

```
import android, time

droid = android.Android()

while 1:
    droid.makeToast("Hello from Python 2.7 for Android")
    time.sleep(5)
```

My application is being started in this way:

```
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.Encoding(QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8)
    ui = MainMenu()
    class MainMenu(QtGui.QWidget):#glavni izbornik
        def __init__(self):
            super(MainMenu, self).__init__()
            i=0
            self.UI(self)

        def UI(self, Form):
            ...
```

What should I change to adopt code to android-python27?

Comment: i ran application from adb shell, and traceback says no module named PyQt4, but I compiled the apk in eclipse using pre-compiled binaries with included PyQt4..

Comment: Have you tried http://modrana.org/trac/wiki/PySideForAndroid?

Comment: no, because it does not have same syntax. Maybe in the end I will try to rewrite code in PySide...